# Is there an equivalent to Python dictionary setdefault for PHP associative arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Python dictionaries, the built-in mapping type for the language have a [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method that returns a value for a key in the dictionary if it's already set, or sets that key to a specified default and then returns it if it is not already set.

Is there an equivalent array function to do this for associative arrays in PHP?

Comment: You want to return a default value of an array key if it doesnt exist? You can use Null coalescing operator http://php.net/manual/fr/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: @David.BC.: good to know, but I also want to set the value in the array if it's not already set.  Would this work?

     $username = $ary['user'] ?? $ary['user'] = 'nobody';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no but you can always write your own

```
public function static setDefault(array &$array, $key, $default = 'None')
{
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $array)){
       $array[$key] = $default;
    }

    return $array[$key];
}
```

Comment: Sadly, you can't use this to chain, like with Python: `foobar.setdefault("level1", {}).setdefault("level 2", {}).setdefault("key", "value")`

Comment: @Flimm you probably can, you will need more abstraction, then return `$this`

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such property for traditional arrays, but you can declare a class that implements [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) and behaves like an array:

```
class DefaultArray implements arrayaccess  {

    private $default='Default Value';

    private $properties=[];

    function __construct($default_value) {
        $this->default=$default_value;
    }

    function offsetSet($property, $value) {
        $this->properties[$property]=$value;
        return $this;
    }

    function offsetGet($property) {
        return isset($this->properties[$property])? $this->properties[$property]:$this->default;
    }

    function offsetExists($property) {
        return isset($this->properties[$property]);
    }

    function offsetUnset($property) {
        unset($this->properties[$offset]);
    }
}


$myArray=new DefaultArray('my default value');

$myArray['bye'] = 'goodbye';

var_dump($myArray['bye']);  // <-- would print 'goodbye'
var_dump($myArray['hello']); // <-- would print 'my default value'
```

Depending on your use case, you could add methods to make it behave like an array also when you serialize it.

Comment: Thanks.  In python `setdefault()` provides key-by-key defaults rather than a collection-wide default as in your example, but it was still good to learn about `implements arrayaccess`.